Jenny and George have broken up

If a marriage breaks up or two people in a romantic relationship break up, their marriage or their relationship ends:
・break up with She's just broken up with her boyfriend.
・Jenny and George have broken up.
https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/break-up

Would the second example sentence work if Jenny and George were friends but not in a romantic relationship?

Not really.
"Break up" could, I suppose, be used in an extended way, if their friendship was particularly close and the ending of the friendship was dramatic, like the ending of a romantic relationship.
With romantic relationships there they are on-or-off.  Two people are either "together" or "not together". With friendships, the degree of closeness varies continuously. So the image of "breaking" doesn't fit with how friendship work.
If two friends have had a quarrel or fight, you could use those words.  "Jenny and George have fought/had a quarrel" for example.
